# using mutate_at from dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with 5 columns and I want to produce 4 additional columns giving my the difference between the last 4 columns and the first column.
I tried the following, but that doesn't work:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- as.tibble(data.frame(A = c(1,2), B = c(3,4), C = c(4,5), D = c(2,3), E = c(4,5)))
r_diff <- function(x,y){
  z = y - x
  return(z)
}
vars_to_process <- c("B","C","D","E")
df %>% mutate_at(.cols=vars_to_process, .funs =r_diff(.,df[,1])) %>% head()
```

Thanks
Renger

Comment: Your `r_diff` function is the (with inverted arguments) `"-"` function, that you can use this way: `"-"(5, 4)`

Comment: If you convert the thing to a matrix you can subtract column 1 from the rest with a "-". Probably 10x or 100x faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a faster solution using base R code. Strategy is convert to a matrix, subtract column one from the required columns, build back into a data frame. Note this only returns the modified columns - if there are columns *not* in `vars_to_process` they'll not appear in the output but you didn't have any of those in your test set so I'll assume they don't exist.

So, always write things in functions whenever possible:

```
bsr = function(df,vars_to_process){
    m = as.matrix(df)
    data.frame(
         A = m[, 1],
             m[, 1] - m[, vars_to_process])}
```

Make some test data:

```
> df = data.frame(matrix(runif(5*1000), ncol=5))
> names(df)=LETTERS[1:5]
> dft = as.tibble(df)
> head(dft)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
          A          B         C         D         E
      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 0.2609174 0.07857624 0.2727817 0.8498004 0.3403234
2 0.3644744 0.95810657 0.8183856 0.2958133 0.4752349
3 0.6042914 0.98793218 0.7547003 0.9596591 0.5354045
4 0.4000441 0.61403331 0.9018804 0.3838347 0.3266855
5 0.6767012 0.11984219 0.9181570 0.5988404 0.6058629
```

Compare with the tidyverse version:

```
akr = function(df,vars_to_process){
   df %>% mutate_at(vars_to_process, funs(r_diff(.,df[[1]])))
   }
```

Check `bsr` and `akr` agree:

```
> head(bsr(dft, vars_to_process))
          A          B           C           D           E
1 0.2609174  0.1823412 -0.01186432 -0.58888295 -0.07940594
2 0.3644744 -0.5936322 -0.45391119  0.06866108 -0.11076050
3 0.6042914 -0.3836408 -0.15040892 -0.35536765  0.06888696
4 0.4000441 -0.2139892 -0.50183635  0.01620939  0.07335861

> head(akr(dft, vars_to_process))
# A tibble: 6 x 5
          A          B           C           D           E
      <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1 0.2609174  0.1823412 -0.01186432 -0.58888295 -0.07940594
2 0.3644744 -0.5936322 -0.45391119  0.06866108 -0.11076050
3 0.6042914 -0.3836408 -0.15040892 -0.35536765  0.06888696
4 0.4000441 -0.2139892 -0.50183635  0.01620939  0.07335861
```

okay, except `akr` returns a tribble but nm. Benchmark:

```
> microbenchmark(bsr(dft, vars_to_process),akr(dft, vars_to_process))
Unit: microseconds
                      expr      min        lq      mean   median       uq
 bsr(dft, vars_to_process)  362.117  388.7215  488.9309  446.123  521.776
 akr(dft, vars_to_process) 8070.391 8365.4230 9853.5239 8673.692 9335.613
```

Base R version is 26 times faster. I'd also argue that subtracting a column from another set of columns is tidier than applying a mutator function but as long as you wrap what your doing in a function it doesn't matter how messy the guts are.

Answer (score 9):

Here's the simplest way to do it.

```
df %>% 
   mutate_at(.vars = vars(B:E),
             .funs = list(~ . - A))
```

The `.vars` argument lets you specify columns in the same way that you would specify columns in `select()`, provided you put that specification inside the function `vars()`.

The `.funs` argument accepts an anonymous function defined on the fly inside a call to `list()`. And you can reference a column in the dataframe (in this case `A`) when defining this anonymous function (see [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209987/using-functions-of-multiple-columns-in-a-dplyr-mutate-at-call)).

In addition, with the release of dplyr 1.0.0, you can now simply do the following:

```
df %>%
   mutate(across(B:E, ~ . - A))
```

Answer (score 4):

We need to subset the column with `[[` as the `[` is still a `data.frame`

```
df %>% 
   mutate_at(vars_to_process, funs(r_diff(.,df[[1]]))) 
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#     A     B     C     D     E
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    -2    -3    -1    -3
#2     2    -2    -3    -1    -3
```