# Create new variables with mutate_at while keeping the original ones

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Consider this simple example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

dataframe <- tibble(helloo = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                        ooooHH = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                        ahaaa = c(200,400,120,300,100,100))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  helloo ooooHH ahaaa
   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1      1      1   200
2      2      1   400
3      3      1   120
4      4      2   300
5      5      2   100
6      6      2   100
```

Here I want to apply the function `ntile` to all the columns that contains `oo`, but I would like these new columns to be called `cat` + the corresponding column.

I know I can do this

```
dataframe %>% mutate_at(vars(contains('oo')), .funs = funs(ntile(., 2)))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  helloo ooooHH ahaaa
   <int>  <int> <dbl>
1      1      1   200
2      1      1   400
3      1      1   120
4      2      2   300
5      2      2   100
6      2      2   100
```

But what I need is this

```
# A tibble: 8 x 5
  helloo   ooooHH   ahaaa cat_helloo cat_ooooHH
     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>    <int>    <int>
1        1        1   200        1        1
2        2        1   400        1        1
3        3        1   120        1        1
4        4        2   300        2        2
5        5        2   100        2        2
6        5        2   100        2        2
7        6        2   100        2        2
8        6        2   100        2        2
```

Is there a solution that does NOT require to store the intermediate data, and merge back to the original dataframe?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

**Update 2020-06 for dplyr 1.0.0**

Starting in **dplyr 1.0.0**, the `across()` function supersedes the "scoped variants" of functions such as `mutate_at()`.  The code should look pretty familiar within `across()`, which is nested inside `mutate()`.

Adding a name to the function(s) you give in the list adds the function name as a suffix.

```
dataframe %>%
     mutate( across(contains('oo'), 
                    .fns = list(cat = ~ntile(., 2))) )

# A tibble: 6 x 5
  helloo ooooHH ahaaa helloo_cat ooooHH_cat
   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>      <int>      <int>
1      1      1   200          1          1
2      2      1   400          1          1
3      3      1   120          1          1
4      4      2   300          2          2
5      5      2   100          2          2
6      6      2   100          2          2
```

Changing the new columns names is a little easier in 1.0.0 with the `.names` argument in `across()`.  Here is an example of adding the function name as a prefix instead of a suffix.  This uses **glue** syntax.

```
dataframe %>%
     mutate( across(contains('oo'), 
                    .fns = list(cat = ~ntile(., 2)),
                    .names = "{fn}_{col}" ) )

# A tibble: 6 x 5
  helloo ooooHH ahaaa cat_helloo cat_ooooHH
   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>      <int>      <int>
1      1      1   200          1          1
2      2      1   400          1          1
3      3      1   120          1          1
4      4      2   300          2          2
5      5      2   100          2          2
6      6      2   100          2          2
```

**Original answer with mutate_at()**

*Edited to reflect changes in dplyr.  As of dplyr 0.8.0, `funs()` is deprecated and `list()` with `~` should be used instead.*

You can give names to the functions to the list you pass to `.funs` to make new variables with the names as suffixes attached.

```
dataframe %>% mutate_at(vars(contains('oo')), .funs = list(cat = ~ntile(., 2)))

# A tibble: 6 x 5
  helloo ooooHH ahaaa helloo_cat ooooHH_cat
   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>      <int>      <int>
1      1      1   200          1          1
2      2      1   400          1          1
3      3      1   120          1          1
4      4      2   300          2          2
5      5      2   100          2          2
6      6      2   100          2          2
```

If you want it as a prefix instead, you could then use `rename_at` to change the names.

```
dataframe %>% 
     mutate_at(vars(contains('oo')), .funs = list(cat = ~ntile(., 2))) %>%
     rename_at( vars( contains( "_cat") ), list( ~paste("cat", gsub("_cat", "", .), sep = "_") ) )

# A tibble: 6 x 5
  helloo ooooHH ahaaa cat_helloo cat_ooooHH
   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>      <int>      <int>
1      1      1   200          1          1
2      2      1   400          1          1
3      3      1   120          1          1
4      4      2   300          2          2
5      5      2   100          2          2
6      6      2   100          2          2
```

Previous code with `funs()` from earlier versions of **dplyr**:

```
dataframe %>% 
     mutate_at(vars(contains('oo')), .funs = funs(cat = ntile(., 2))) %>%
     rename_at( vars( contains( "_cat") ), funs( paste("cat", gsub("_cat", "", .), sep = "_") ) )
```

Comment: I guess one can always write some regex stuff to change the name of the `col_cat` variables?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Yep.  Possibly in `rename_at` for convenience; added example in edit.

Comment: The renaming appears to only append if there's more than one column that contains a match. 

Is there a way to make it append for a single match too? 

Example: `dataframe %>% mutate_at(vars(contains('ah')), .funs = funs(cat = ntile(., 2))) `

Comment: @bheavner Not that I know of, but you might ask a new question.  For a single variable you could write a function using `mutate` and set the variable names based on the function input.  See the "Setting variable names" section of [Programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html)

Comment: If you want to know what exactly do the `~ntile(., 2)`this function map smallest inputs to smallest outputs so in this case the col `ooooHH` the first three values `1,2,3` rank as 1 and the `4,5,6` rank as 2. 
(e.g compare `hello` column with `cat_hello` if I rank `~ntile(., 5))`
use `.fns = list(cat = ~(.)*10)` if you only want to mutate 
based on a product of row values.