# Keeping original variables with dplyr::mutate_at & varying length of dynamic variables

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I ran across an excellent SO post/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947787/create-new-variables-with-mutate-at-while-keeping-the-original-ones), which demonstrates that original variables can be retained with `dplyr::mutate_at` while new variables are created with user-defined suffixes. The code runs as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
dataframe <- data_frame(
  helloo = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  ooooHH = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  ahaaa = c(200, 400, 120, 300, 100, 100)
)

dataframe %>%
  mutate_at(
    vars(contains("oo")),
    .funs = funs(cat = ntile(., 2))
  )
```

which produces

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  helloo ooooHH ahaaa helloo_cat ooooHH_cat
   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>      <int>      <int>
1      1      1   200          1          1
2      2      1   400          1          1
3      3      1   120          2          2
```

However, it seems to be the case that if there is only one variable for `vars`, this suffix scheme does not work as above: for example:

```
varlist <- c('ooooHH')
dataframe %>% 
  mutate_at(
    vars(varlist), 
    .funs = funs(cat = ntile(., 2))
  )
```

produces output as

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  helloo ooooHH ahaaa   cat
   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1      1      1   200     1
2      2      1   400     1
3      3      1   120     2
```

I understand the rational---there is no need to distinguish the new variables if only one variable is mutated. However, I desire to have `cat` column named as `ooooHH_cat` for consistency, because I will do this multiple times and the dynamic column names that go into `vars` will vary in length. In addition, I wish to preserve the result for when

```
varlist <- c('helloo', 'ooooHH')
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Since , the strings are there in a variable, we cannot hardcode it.

```
varlist <- c('helloo', 'ooooHH')
```

we can modify the function to rename `varlist` object instead.

```
dataframe %>% 
  mutate_at(
  vars(varlist), 
   .funs = funs(cat = ntile(., 2))
 ) %>%
rename_at(vars(grep("^cat$", names(.))), 
          funs(sub("cat", paste0(varlist, "_cat"), .)))
```

---

**Original Answer**

A hackish way from the same link would be using `rename_at` to replace only when we find an exact match for "cat"

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe %>% 
  mutate_at(
    vars('ooooHH'), 
    .funs = funs(cat = ntile(., 2))
   ) %>%
rename_at(vars(grep("^cat$", names(.))), funs(sub("cat", "ooooHH_cat", .))) 

#   helloo ooooHH ahaaa ooooHH_cat
#   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>      <int>
#1   1.00   1.00   200          1
#2   2.00   1.00   400          1
#3   3.00   1.00   120          1
#4   4.00   2.00   300          2
#5   5.00   2.00   100          2
#6   6.00   2.00   100          2
```

It would not impact when there are more than one column and the renaming is already applied.

```
dataframe %>%
   mutate_at(
   vars(contains("oo")),
    .funs = funs(cat = ntile(., 2))
  ) %>%
 rename_at(vars(grep("^cat$", names(.))), funs(sub("cat", "ooh_cat", .))) 


#   helloo ooooHH ahaaa helloo_cat ooooHH_cat
#   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>      <int>      <int>
#1   1.00   1.00   200          1          1
#2   2.00   1.00   400          1          1
#3   3.00   1.00   120          1          1
#4   4.00   2.00   300          2          2
#5   5.00   2.00   100          2          2
#6   6.00   2.00   100          2          2
```

Comment: One thing---suppose `'ooooHH'` gets fed into the function as a general vector of column names---for example, `varlist <- c('ooooHH')` which will be used as `vars(varlist)`. So I don't want to use exact characters for `sub`. How would I go about that?

Comment: @Kim in that case, How about `dataframe %>% 
  mutate_at(
    vars(varlist), 
    .funs = funs(cat = ntile(., 2))
  ) %>%
rename_at(vars(grep("^cat$", names(.))), funs(sub("cat", paste0(varlist, "_cat"), .))) 
` ?

Comment: That does not quite seem to work when `varlist <- c('ooooHH', 'helloo')`, that's the thing. :(

Comment: @Kim It seems to work right? It just gives the warning but I think it is ok to ignore since it never reaches that part of the code for multiple elements in `varlist`. It will only change column name when it finds an exact match for "cat".

Comment: Aha I must have mistook something---you are right. I can ignore the warning. Thanks a lot!