# Challenge Replacing Soft-deprecated funs_() within mutate_at

Tags: r, dplyr

I had written a function that creates lag transformation for variables in data frame. Now as dplyr has soft depreciated funs_ argument, it's giving me warning to use list in place of funs_. below given is my lag transformation function which is working fine but I want to modify it using updated argument list.

```
lagTransformation<- function(ds,n)
{
  # this function creats lag transformation of dataframe
  # args:
  # ds : Dataset
  # n : number of lags

  require(dplyr)
  lags <- seq(n)
  lag_names <- paste("lag", formatC(lags, width = nchar(max(lags)), flag = "0"), sep = "")
  lag_functions <- setNames(paste("dplyr::lag(., ", lags, ")"), lag_names)
  ds <-ds %>% mutate_at(vars(names(ds)), funs_(lag_functions)) %>% select(contains("_lag"))
  return(ds)
}
```

Tried replacing funs_ with list but got an error

```
lagTransformation<- function(ds,n)
{
  # this function creats lag transformation of dataframe
  # args:
  # ds : Dataset
  # n : number of lags

  require(dplyr)
  lags <- seq(n)
  lag_names <- paste("lag", formatC(lags, width = nchar(max(lags)), flag = "0"), sep = "")
  lag_functions <- setNames(paste("dplyr::lag(., ", lags, ")"), lag_names)
  ds <-ds %>% mutate_at(vars(names(ds)), list(~.lag_functions)) %>% select(contains("_lag"))
  return(ds)
}
```

Error in get(.x, .env, mode = "function") : 
  object 'dplyr::lag(.,  1 )' of mode 'function' was not found

referred below question but not able to rectify the error

[Create new variables with mutate_at while keeping the original ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947787/create-new-variables-with-mutate-at-while-keeping-the-original-ones)

what modification I need?

Comment: `paste("dplyr::lag(., ", lags, ")")` This won't work unless you `eval` `parse` it(eval(parse) has its own disadvantages).

Comment: Tried with eval and parse too, results is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `purrr::map` to set up the list of `lag_functions` this can be achieved like so

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

lagTransformation<- function(ds,n)
{
  # this function creats lag transformation of dataframe
  # args:
  # ds : Dataset
  # n : number of lags

  require(dplyr)
  lags <- seq(n)
  lag_names <- paste("lag", formatC(lags, width = nchar(max(lags)), flag = "0"), sep = "")
  lag_functions <- purrr::map(lags, ~ function(x) dplyr::lag(x, .x)) %>% 
    setNames(lag_names)
  ds <- ds %>% mutate_at(vars(names(ds)), lag_functions) %>% select(contains("_lag"))
  return(ds)
}

lagTransformation(mtcars[1:4], 2) %>% head()
#>   mpg_lag1 cyl_lag1 disp_lag1 hp_lag1 mpg_lag2 cyl_lag2 disp_lag2 hp_lag2
#> 1       NA       NA        NA      NA       NA       NA        NA      NA
#> 2     21.0        6       160     110       NA       NA        NA      NA
#> 3     21.0        6       160     110     21.0        6       160     110
#> 4     22.8        4       108      93     21.0        6       160     110
#> 5     21.4        6       258     110     22.8        4       108      93
#> 6     18.7        8       360     175     21.4        6       258     110
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>