# How to relocate several columns in one step using dplyr::relocate?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to reorder some columns to come after a particular other column using dplyr::relocate. Here is a MWE:

```
a <- letters[1:3]
b <- letters[4:6]
c <- letters[7:9]
d <- letters[10:12]

mytib <- tibble::tibble(a,b,c,d)

#  A tibble: 3 x 4
#  a     b     c     d    
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 a     d     g     j    
# 2 b     e     h     k    
# 3 c     f     i     l    

mytib %>%
     relocate(c, .after = a)
```

This example works but is there a way that I could, with one relocate command, move c after a and, say, d after b?

I tried the following without success:

```
mytib %>%
     relocate(c(c, d), .after(c(a, b)))
```

Edit 1: I explicitly ask about `relocate` because functions like `select` do not work for large datasets where all I know is after which column (name) I want to insert a column.

Edit 2: This is my expected output:

```
#  A tibble: 3 x 4
#  a     c     b     d    
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 a     g     d     j    
# 2 b     h     e     k    
# 3 c     i     f     l
```

Comment: Typo? `.after = c(a, b)`

Comment: I don't think that it could be used that way. For this task, I think that you should use `select()`: `mytib %>%
 select(a, c, b, d)`.

Comment: Using OP's vectors, this works for me `tibble(c, d, a, b) %>% relocate(c(c, d), .after = c(a, b))`

Comment: @arg0naut91 I think it does not work: a should be after c, while d should be after b. Here it is a, b, c, d.

Comment: @tmfmnk, ah OK I see - there was no expected output so I've just noticed the typo. Indeed I agree that `relocate` may not be of help here.

Comment: I fixed the typo. ```mytib %>% select(a,c,b,d)``` only works for small datasets. Is there a scalable alternative that a) does not rely on numeric column indices and b) does not require me to type out the order of all columns?

Comment: I think I found a halfway elegant solution using `purrr::reduce` - posted it as an answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `dplyr::relocate` itself apparently doesn't allow relocating in pairs, you can "hack" this behavior by preparing a list of column pairs like the ones you describe ("c after a" & "d after b") and `reduce` over that list, passing your df in as an `.init` value and in each reduce-step relocating one pair.

Like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df_relocated <- reduce(
  .x = list(c('c','a'), c('d','b')), 
  .f = ~ relocate(.x, .y[1], .after = .y[2]),
  .init = mytib
)
```

This produces a tibble just as you expect it:

```
> df_relocated
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  a     c     b     d    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     g     d     j    
2 b     h     e     k    
3 c     i     f     l
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to work with two lists, where element 1 of list 2 should relocated after element 1 of list 1 and so forth, this would be a solution:

```
 reduce2(
  .x = c("a", "b"),
  .y = c("c", "d"),
  .f = ~ relocate(..1, ..3, .after = ..2),
  .init = mytib
  )
```

Comment: With `dplyr version 1.0.7` I got an error; `Can't subset columns that don't exist. x Column \`..2\` doesn't exist.`  Putting `..2` and `..3`  in curly braces helped: `.f = ~ relocate(..1, {..3}, .after = {..2}),`.