# How to use sQuote only in columns containing as a column name a specified string

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to add single quotes to a value in a dataframe in the first row of columns containing in their name a string *intensity*.

Change:

```
A     B     C    IntensityA ssIntensityB

asa   adf   df   123      183
as    sd    sd   121      41
```

to:

```
A     B     C    IntensityA ssIntensityB

asa   adf   df   '123'      '183'
as    sd    sd   121        41
```

I have tried the following:

```
int_col <- grep("intensity", colnames(tab), value=TRUE, invert=FALSE)
int_c <- colnames(tab) %in% int_col
q <- sQuote(subset(Access.protein.input,int_c))
```

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: Instead of just the first row it is ok to modify the whole intensity column.

Comment: `dplyr::mutate_at` is designed for modifying certain columns (selected by name using various methods) by applying a function to them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using functions of multiple columns in a dplyr mutate\_at call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209987/using-functions-of-multiple-columns-in-a-dplyr-mutate-at-call)