# R - mutate a subset of columns only on a subset of rows

Tags: r, dplyr

My goal is to modify the values of certain columns (chosen through their names) only on a subset of rows that verify a certain condition, using `dplyr`.

I have this toy dataframe

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(42)
df1 <- data.frame(
  Date = rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-31"), "day"), each = 24),
  A1 = runif(744, min = 0, max = 1000),
  A2 = runif(744, min = 0, max = 1000),
  B1 = runif(744, min = 0, max = 1000),
  B2 = runif(744, min = 0, max = 1000)
)
```

Let's say I want to multiply by 0.2 the values of the columns that start with the letter "B" only in the rows whose `Date` is either `2020-01-01` or `2020-01-06`. The code in this case is pretty simple:

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(
    B1 = if_else(Date %in% as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-06")), 0.2 * B1, B1),
    B2 = if_else(Date %in% as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-06")), 0.2 * B2, B2)
  )
```

However, if I have a lot of variables starting with the letter "B" I want to do this in an automatic way. I've tried `mutate_at` in the following chunk of code

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate_at(
    vars(starts_with("B")),
    if_else(Date %in% as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-06")), 0.2 * ., .)
  )
```

but R gives me the following error:

```
Error in Date %in% as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-06")) : 
object "Date" not found
```

What am I doing wrong? I've looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096162/dplyr-mutate-replace-several-columns-on-a-subset-of-rows) but I would like to find a way that does not define a custom function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209987/using-functions-of-multiple-columns-in-a-dplyr-mutate-at-call) for more info

```
df1 %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("B")),
            .funs = list(~ if_else(Date %in% as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-06")), 0.2 * ., .)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for pointing me towards an old good question with the explanations. I didn't find it when I was looking for an answer