# If value in x exists in y, copy multiple values from y rows to corresponding x rows

Tags: r, dplyr

My data and packages used:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(id = c(1:3, rep(4, 3), 5:6),
                   id1 = c(7:9, 1:3, 10:11),
                   value = 1:8 * 10,
                   value1 = 1:8 * 20,
                   chkvar = c(rep(TRUE, 3), rep(FALSE, 3), rep(TRUE, 2)))
```

If chkvar == FALSE, I want to replace the values in id1 and value1 with the corresponding values where id1 is in id. I can achieve this in two steps:

```
data %>%
  mutate(value1 = ifelse(chkvar == FALSE,
                         value1[match(id1, id)],
                         value1),
         id1 = ifelse(chkvar == FALSE,
                      id1[match(id1, id)],
                      id1))

  id id1 value value1 chkvar
1  1   7    10     20   TRUE
2  2   8    20     40   TRUE
3  3   9    30     60   TRUE
4  4   7    40     20  FALSE
5  4   8    50     40  FALSE
6  4   9    60     60  FALSE
7  5  10    70    140   TRUE
8  6  11    80    160   TRUE
```

but my full dataset has more columns to replace, hence wanting a solution requiring less code. I tried adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41152235/2530121):

```
data %>%
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(value1, id1),
            .funs = list(~ifelse(!chkvar, value1[match(id1, id)], .)))
```

but I cannot work out how to declare more than one column if !chkvar is TRUE. I seems to me like a simple task but perhaps it's not possible using `ifelse()`? The other answers I found involved using `coalesce()` but I don't have missing values or I could not work out how to adapt the code. The `case_when()` solutions I found also required a separate declaration for each column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track.  You can use `across()` to select multiple variables to apply your transformation to:

```
library(dplyr)

data |>
  mutate(across(c(value1, id1), ~ if_else(!chkvar, .x[match(id1, id)], .x)))

  id id1 value value1 chkvar
1  1   7    10     20   TRUE
2  2   8    20     40   TRUE
3  3   9    30     60   TRUE
4  4   7    40     20  FALSE
5  4   8    50     40  FALSE
6  4   9    60     60  FALSE
7  5  10    70    140   TRUE
8  6  11    80    160   TRUE
```

Comment: I actually got super close to this, even had the `across()` statement the same. It was the .x that was beyond me.